# Is there a way to get Selenium ChromeDriver script logs as events in .NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium ChromeDriver to navigate to a website, that generates console logs. I know I can read these logs with `chromeDriver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser)`, but this is slow, and very inefficient because it returns all the logs whenever it's called.

I would like to do an event-based approach instead, so whenever a new log entry is generated, an event is fired in my C# code with the new log entry. I haven't found any resources online about this, so I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Those are browser logs... you could probably poll the file for changes.  See here for location: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271282?hl=en

Comment: I wonder if you can do `window.console = { your own object };` in JavaScript, so you can override console.log(...), console.info(...), console.error(...) etc.